# want to replace from google Reverse Geocoding with Nominatim Reverse Geocoding

Tags: reverse, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

How to change with nominatim goecode?

```
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': remote_ip_info.city}, function(results, status) { 
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                     map.setZoom(8);
                  } else { 
                    //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); 
                  } 
                });
```